# How to query a list django

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

```
def get_queryset(self):
    result = Tenants.objects.all()
    filters = self.request.GET.get('filter')

    if filters is not None:
        filters = filters[1] if filters[1] == ',' else filters
        filters_list = filters.split(',')
        filter_result = Tenants.objects.none()
        for value in filters_list:
            filter_result = filter_result | result.filter(Q(business_type__icontains=value)
            |Q(category__icontains=value))
        return filter_result
    
    return result.all()
```

here i want the query parameters to be business_type and category
when using get method and checking the data i am only able to filter one field either business_type or category

when using filter twice like
/?page=1&filter=business_type&filter=category then i am getting the data i want

but i need the data when the url is like
/?page=1&filter=business_type,category

Comment: you can use regex on the URL to get the different filters, or separate the filter parameter using "," as a regex split

Comment: What is the `filters = filters[1] if filters[1] == ',' else filters` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here can be used lookup [**`in`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)) filter `business_type__in=filters.split(",")`.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    result = Tenants.objects.all()
    filters = self.request.GET.get('filter')

    if filters:
        filter_result = result.filter(business_type__in=filters.split(","))
        return filter_result
    
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query with:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    result = Tenants.objects.all()
    filters = self.request.GET.getlist('filter')
    if not filters:
        return Tenants.objects.all()
    Tenants.objects.filter(
        Q(*[
            Q(business_type__icontains=value) | Q(category__icontains=value)
            for filter in filters
            for value in filter.split(',') if value
        ],
        _connector=Q.OR
        )
    )
```